# How to change GNOME default screen rotation

Tags: xorg, gnome, monitors, resolution

How do I change the **default screen rotation** for my gnome desktop? Is there anyway I can change the monitor settings without logging in?

[image: Two monitors rotated]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do so by modifying the Xorg.conf by adding the line

```
Section "Monitor"
     Identifier      "Monitor1"
     Option  "Rotate"        "left"
EndSection
```

or after login use the `xrandr` command as:

> xrandr --output DVI-2 --rotate left

Replace DVI-2 and left as per your requirement

xrandr solution will be effective till session exist. On reboot, the changes will be lost whereas xorg.conf setting will be reboot-persistant

Comment: How to do this when using Wayland? This solution is not GNOME-specific.